# Professor offered to write a letter without prompting

Tags: recommendation-letter

I’m applying for a fellowship, and I contacted one of the professors to ask him about his experience (just tenured last year, but very well-known in the field and won that fellowship in 2014). We’ve interacted several times before (he also knows my work), but I’m quite surprised that he’s very enthusiastic and even offered to write a letter on my behalf if I need it. I’m also thinking of getting him as external member in my PhD thesis committee, and he also told me he’d be happy to work with me.

Is it true that this is a clear signal about the quality of the letter? As I understand, professors never agree to write a letter if they can’t write a good one, let alone offer without prompting.

Comment: What else could it mean?

Answer (score 31):

I would take it as a polite offer from someone who has recently been in the position of needing to ask for these letters and knows it can be difficult to find people you are comfortable asking.

You'll have to decide on your own who your best letters will come from, but yes I would expect someone who knows your work and has offered to write a letter to be someone who will write a positive recommendation. Someone on your committee is typically a good choice. If you haven't formed a committee yet, a potential committee member who is familiar with your work sounds like a decent option, though your priority should start with people who work with you most directly and then filter out to your broader network.

Comment: Yes I have already had 2 letters from my advisors in the department. Does this add a bit of context?

Comment: @Jeremy How many letters do you need? If you've already asked everyone who knows you better and you need one more, this person seems like a great choice. If you don't need any more letters then you don't need to ask for another one.

Comment: Yes I need at least 3, so I would ask him to write me a letter. Thank you for advising me

Answer (score 8):

Generally such an offer would indicate strong support but you need to judge. If the person knows you and your work well then that would support the guess that it is a strongly positive sign.

But think about whether it is support for you, personally, or support for the fellowship itself and just a desire to create a large pool of applicants. That is a possibility, though, probably somewhat remote.

Comment: Yes he knows me quite well, and he has a strong reputation in the field as being very generous to his students and mentees. This is a strong signal?

Comment: I would think it so, though I know very little of your relationship.

Comment: I think our relationship is pretty good. He gave me a lot of useful advice and feedback on my works, though we have been knowing each other for around a year.

Answer (score 3):

Professors' time is scarce and valuable to them, so anytime a professor volunteers their time, you can be sure that they value what they're offering to do.

As a professor myself, I am happy to write recommendation letters for lots of people who ask me to—but when I proactively offer to write a recommendation letter for someone, it's a very positive sign (I want them to know that I consider them really well suited for continuing in the field).